# How to get static files to work in Django | Favicon not getting loaded but appears when entering that directory

Tags: python, html, django, favicon, django-staticfiles

I'm having trouble trying to get my static files to work, I've already tried different answers for a long time and I'm getting confused what's the problem. I was trying to load my css with debug turned off, but I think its normal for the css not to appear since django doesn't load static files with debug turned off. My problem was when trying to put a favicon into my test website. I also think in the future I'll have complications with JS, etc..

**main.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Hello, Django</title>

        <!-- load staticfiles-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main.css' %}">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "favicon.ico" %}}" type="image/png">

    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from f1trackerapp import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.f1trackerapp, name="f1trackerapp"),
    path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('favicon.ico')))
]
```

**settings.py (stackoverflow doesn't let me post full settings.py code)**

```
...
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
...
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'f1trackerapp',
]
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'f1stats.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**Errors:**
*"GET /static/favicon.ico%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 1911*

My project directory looks like this:

```
F1stats
    .venv
    .vscode
    f1stats (project)
        --project files--
    f1trackerapp (app)
        --app files--
        templates
            main.html
        migrations
    static
        favicon.ico.png
        main.css
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
    requirements.txt
```

I already read many documents, and stackoverflow posts, nothing really helped me just made me more confused.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove one `}` in your template `{% static "favicon.ico" %}}`. You wrongly added two curly brackets at the end. You can see that as the url has an extra/wrong `%7D` behind your url.

Comment: Thanks I just realized it today when I woke up, but thanks for the help!